# Shell programs do not refresh the screen correctly

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

When I press PageUp or PageDown in ranger or cmus, the screen doesn't refresh correctly, some characters and even lines are not updated. I believe it started with macos upgrade from 13.4.5 to 13.5.1

Tried same programs in Terminal.app, iTerm, Allacrity. Tried in bash also, instead of zsh. Tried to clear my shell configs and clear $PATH. Nothing helps.

What can cause that? I suppose it is somehow related with ncurses.

Comment: type "reset" and return key

Comment: Does not fix anything. As I said, it behaves so even in different shells.

Comment: Having a wrong value of `$TERM` could easily cause such behavior.

Comment: I know. But the $TERM value is ok and managed with terminal application, I've even checked $COLORTERM, all is normal. But still this bug appeared in any terminal application and with clean shell rc files... I believe something is wrong with ncurses sending something wrongly with WINCH signal. Maybe this vulnerability fix is the culprit? 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2023/09/14/uncursing-the-ncurses-memory-corruption-vulnerabilities-found-in-library/
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213843

Comment: I need a confirmation from other ncurses based TUI applications users with macos 13.5.1+ if they have the same bug or not.

Comment: Does your screen get refreshed incorrectly after a window size change? You didn't mention this in your original post. If not then WINCH is unrelated.

Comment: Sometimes it is also corrupted, yes. But mostly just lines do not update correctly on screen change. Previous characters are left where spaces were.